# Cross-correlation maximum in frequency domain

Tags: fft, cross-correlation, correlation

I need to compute the complex cross-correlation between two signals *a* and *b* and the take only the maximum value of the cross-correlation, regardless of the lag time where this occurs. I can do it either in time domain or in frequency domain. This needs to be later incorporated in a FPGA, so I want to be efficient.

An alternative is to go to frequency domain correlation, but I would need to do

```
max(IFFT(FFT(a)*conj(FFT(b))))
```

which is probably computationally costly.

**Is there a way to avoid going back and forth twice to the frequency and time domain?**

Comment: You need to limit the maximum time lag to some reasonable number and the best choice of algorithm depends on what this number is

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $a$ and $b$ are of length $N$, the cross-correlation is calculated using the convolution operator which has complexity $O(Nm)$ for $m$ different lags ([source](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.147.7724&rep=rep1&type=pdf)), meaning the operation takes $N$ times $m$ real-valued multiplications. Addition is usually much faster than multiplication which is why it is typically ignored in [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)*. Going the frequency domain route requires **three** FFT/IFFT operations each with complexity $O(N \log_2 N)$ ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform)), and one element-wise complex product $O(3N)$ (the 3 comes from this [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Complex_multiplication_algorithm)). Summing these complexities results in

$$3\ O(N \log_2 N)+O(3N)=O(N(3+3 \log_2 N))$$
Both methods will have the same complexity for performing the maximum and absolute value, so I will omit those operations.

Comparing the two, $Nm$ will be larger than $N(3+3 \log_2 N)$ when $m>3+3 \log_2 N$. If this statement is true, it will be more efficient to use the frequency-domain method. Otherwise, you would be better using the convolution method.

*This statement isn't always valid on modern computing hardware because the speed of multiplication has increased substantially in the past decade to the point where addition and multiplication take roughly the same time to compute.

Comment: True (+1), but see Hilmar’s comment on the OP.

Comment: @PeterK. In an effort to improve the response, I've opened the answer up to the community.

Comment: I agree with the points raised and also to Hilmar's comment especially if the number of lags can be reduced. I don't understand the rationale under computing the O values and how you get to the 1+3logN. I think understanding this can help me in comparing both implementations also depending on the number of lags. Thanks!

Comment: One thing, time domain convolution takes real multiplication and add, while frequency domain convolution takes complex multiplication-add, which results in a slightly different turning point.

Comment: @ZRHan, thank you for bringing this up. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Ash thanks for the clarification. The log notation, shouldn't it be log2 precisely?

Comment: @Albert That is correct.

Comment: @Ash I just noted you mentioned that O(N·m) means that the operation takes N times m real-valued multiplications. But what happens if the two signals are complex? This in fact applies to both the time and the frequency domain paths. And for the FFT of complex signals, perhaps the length of the FFT should be 2N instead of N. Also, the multiplication, shouldn't we take the numbers from here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations instead of O(3n)?